# SQL server wont start automatically after OS upgrade

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, upgrade, startup, enterprise-edition

I did an in place upgrade for host OS from Windows server 2012 R2 to windows server 2022. After this move, I noticed the SQL server 2017 enterprise edition instance therein does not start automatically across reboots; but picks up when manually started from services. Any possible cause for this? This is a box purely dedicated to the SQL server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using a gMSA account for the SQL service. To resolve this, I went to the windows pane of the OS event logon and noticed an error from NETLOGON hinting that the domain controller was unavailable or could not be contacted and a subsequent error from the Service Control Manager  tagged the SQL username or password could be unavailable. I went to the registry editor's HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQLSERVER and on the key DependOnService I added W32Time and Netlogon as shown in the image below.  [image: sql depencies]